# add_p(...) from gtsummary package doesn't work on survfit class

Tags: r, survival-analysis, gtsummary

I'm working on a survival analysis project. I have a few strata variables to generate KM estimates, log-rank test p-values as well as KM curves.

I found the package gtsummary could save me a lot of time by the following:

```
fit_os_menopausal = survival::survfit(Surv(os_time_yrs, os_event, type = "right") ~ menopausal_status, data = data)

gtsummary::tbl_survfit(fit_os_menopausal,
                   times = c(1,2,3,5,8),
                   label_header = "**{time} year freedom**", 
                   estimate_fun = function(.x){style_percent(.x, digits = 1, symbol = TRUE)})%>%
gtsummary::add_n()%>%
gtsummary::add_nevent()%>%
gtsummary::add_p(test = list(menopausal_status ~ "logrank"))
```

From their webpage, the examples are below https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/add_p.tbl_survfit.html

The error returns as "There was an error in 'add_p()/add_difference()' for variable 'menopausal_status', p-value omitted:
Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE): cannot coerce class ‘"survfit"’ to a data.frame"

I checked online and haven't had any luck yet...I'm wondering if anyone else has the same issue otherwise I'll report this as a bug to them lol

Comment: Please update your post with a minimal reproducible example (aka a reprex) that we can run on our machines. Then we can help you out.

Comment: ...I made a mock data and it worked. But I had no idea why my data didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)
library(survival)

mockdata = data.frame(
  event = c(rep(0,45), rep(1,5)),
  time = sample(seq(0,20,0.1), size = 50, replace = TRUE),
  sex = sample(c("Female", "Male"), size = 50, replace = TRUE)
)


fit_os = survival::survfit(Surv(time, event, type = "right") ~ sex, data 
= mockdata)
survdiff(Surv(time, event, type = "right") ~ sex, data = 
mockdata)$pvalue

summary(fit_os)

gtsummary::tbl_survfit(fit_os,
                   times = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                   label = list(sex ~ "Sex"),
                   label_header = "**{time}-year freedom**", 
                   estimate_fun = function(.x){style_percent(.x, digits 
= 1, symbol = TRUE)})%>%
  gtsummary::add_n()%>%
  gtsummary::add_nevent()%>%
  gtsummary::add_p(test = everything() ~ "logrank")
```

somehow...this mock data works for add_p but my real data doesn't!

Comment: Sometimes you can share a small portion of your data with `dput(data)` to illustrate the issue.